# CtUnaryOperator extends CtStatement

Tags: inria-spoon

I can't understand why.

In the expression `if (a++ > 0) {...}` `a++` can't be a Statement but since `a++` is a `CtUnaryOperator` then it's also a `CtStatement`.

How can I differentiate between `a++;` and `i = a++;` since in both cases `a++` will be a `CtStatement`?

Answer (score 0):

to differentiate between both, one looks at the parent. One class encapsulates this logic:

```
// does element act as a statement?
boolean hasStatementRole = new LineFilter().matches(element)
```

Comment: The following cases leads to problems determining if an `CtStatement` is indeed a java Statement using the `getParent()` aproach.

`foo(bar(a++));`
`if ((i = a++) > n) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Since the issues in this questions comes from design decisions in the Spoon tool, it can't be answered properly.